# X and Y are two independent standard gaussian variables, what is the Probability that X>100*Y?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

We want to find $P(X> 100*Y)$.

My strategy was to first express $X>100*Y$ as $X-100*Y>0$ and express $Z=X-100*Y$.
$Z$ should be another normal random variable, yet not standard. My approach further was to standardise it so I can use 68–95–99.7 rule. However this approach is leading nowhere.

Can anyone give any hints how I should approach it?

Comment: Can you calculate the mean and standard deviation of $Z$ ?

Comment: The combined mean is $-99$ and the combined variance is $10001$, so...

Comment: @ParclyTaxel : the combined mean is zero

Comment: It is said in the problem that $X$ and $Y$ are normal so the mean would be just 0 there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really like your method of using $Z = X - 100\cdot Y$

You were definitely correct in pointing out $Z$ is again Normal! We can characterize every normal distribution by its mean and variance. So to find out $Z$ exactly we just need these two things.

**Mean of Z**

You will have seen before that expectation is "linear" that is we know $\mathbb{E}[Z] = \mathbb{E}[X] - 100\cdot \mathbb{E}[Y] = 0 - 100\cdot 0 = 0$

**Variance of Z**

This is slightly harder, in general variance doesn't add up nicely but because $X$ and $Y$ are independent then it will! 
Var$[Z] = $ Var$[X] + 100^2 $Var$[Y] = 1+10,000 = 10,001$

**Finishing off**

Hence $Z \sim N(0,10001)$  
And because Normal distributions are symmetric about their mean we know $\mathbb{P}[Z > 0 ] = \frac{1}{2}$

(Yes we didn't need to calculate the variance at all)

**Another approach**

I first saw this question a while back and used a different method. Yours I think is much better but I will include mine here.

We find the probability of $X>100\cdot Y $ by conditioning on $4$ events, namely the signs of the two random variables. Notice that as $X$ and $Y$ are standard normal they both have equal probability of being positive or negative.

1. $X>0$ , $Y<0$. In this case we know for certain $X>100Y$
2. $X<0$, $Y > 0$. In this case we know for certain $X < 100Y$
3. $X>0$, $Y>0$. Let $p$ be the probability of $X>100Y$ when they are both positive.
4. $X<0$ , $Y<0$. By symmetry the probability of $X>100Y$ is $1-p$

Hence $\mathbb{P}[X>100Y] = \frac{1}{4}(1+0+p+1-p) = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I was just thinking the same thing about the symmetry of Normal distribution around mean.

Comment: @SAT thank you! you almost had it. i added a little extra to my answer on how i first approached this problem

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $X $ and $Y$ are independent random variables with $$ X\sim N(\ \mu_x,\ \sigma^2_x\ ),\quad Y\sim N(\ \mu_y,\ \sigma^2_y\ ).\ $$

Then,

$$-100Y \sim N(\ -100\mu_y,\ 100^2 \sigma^2_y\ )\ ,\quad $$

and so

$$X-100Y = X + (-100Y) \sim N(\ \mu_x - 100\mu_y,\ \sigma^2_x\ + 100^2 \sigma^2_y\ ). $$

Therefore,

$$P(X>100Y) = P(X-100Y>0) = \ldots$$

Comment: you rv $X-100Y$ has a negative variance

Comment: Hmm... I suck at statistics, so I guess I'm going to learn something here, which is good.

Comment: $V(X-aY)=V(X)+a^2V(Y)$

Comment: @tommik, yeah that makes sense,